# Configurar Base de datos Amazon RDS en Workbench

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Cordial saludo.

He creado una base de datos en RDS (Mysql), hice las pruebas de conexión, en este caso haciendo uso de NodeJS la prueba fue exitosa, pero la base de datos no posee tabla alguna, deseo realizar la conexión de la base de datos a Workbench para crear dichas tablas, estoy siguiendo el siguiente manual: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k68Y-XYapEI

En él se indica que debo tener un certificado .pem, en la creación de la base de datos no se indica en dónde debo descargar dicho archivo.

Agradezco mucho la atención y espero haber sido claro con mi duda.

Jorge Rubiano.

Answer (score 0):

El certificado no es estrictamente necesario.
¿Cuál es exactamente tu problema a la hora de crear la base de datos?
Lo más probable es que tengas problemas de conectividad por con RDS.

Asegurate de tener el puerto **3306** TCP debidamente habilitado en el grupo de seguridad asociado a tu instancia RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que al momento de haber creado tu instancia hayas permitido las conexiones remotas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También permite el puerto 3306 a un RDS.